# Calling a completionHandler when an error occurs

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Im trying to pass a bool to my completion handler. When the app works, the result of passing the bool to my completion handler determines what alert I display. If I call it inside my error check, the app crashes/locks up. If I call it anywhere else, everything works as expected? I'm lost and can't find the answer to this one. Please help.

```
class func TestConnection(_ urlBase: String, usingCommand command: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let urlString = urlBase + "/" + command
        var IsValidConnection = false
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completionHandler(IsValidConnection)
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in      
            //App blows up when running this block of code.
            //Doesn't return. App crashes/locks up
            guard error == nil else {
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }
            //App works as expected when running code below
            guard let _: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                completionHandler(false)
                return
            }

            let serverResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

            if serverResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                IsValidConnection = true
            }

            completionHandler(IsValidConnection)

        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code.  There is nothing wrong with what you have posted, so it is likely something else.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `URLSession.shared.dataTask` has its own `completionHandler` named `completionHandler`. Just rename your handler to `testConnectionCompletionHandler`:

```
class func TestConnection(_ urlBase: String, usingCommand command: String, testConnectionCompletionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let urlString = urlBase + "/" + command
    var IsValidConnection = false
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        testConnectionCompletionHandler(IsValidConnection)
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in      
        //App blows up when running this block of code.
        //Doesn't return. App crashes/locks up
        guard error == nil else {
            testConnectionCompletionHandler(false)
            return
        }
        //App works as expected when running code below
        guard let _: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            testConnectionCompletionHandler(false)
            return
        }

        let serverResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

        if serverResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            IsValidConnection = true
        }

        testConnectionCompletionHandler(IsValidConnection)

    }.resume()
}
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask

Comment: Besides the naming issue OP could simply use `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { _, response, _ in
            completion((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200)
        }.resume()`

Comment: Thank you both for your advice!